# How to dynamically change property of an Ionic element in angular html template?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, observable

I would like to change the outline property of ionic-chip if an observable changes:

```
<span *ngIf="(avgRating | async) as obs">
      <ion-chip  outline= "obs.total  > 0 ? 'none' : 'outline'"> 
        // change outline property if observable changes
      </ion-chip>
</span>
```

Is it possible to do this in the template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outline property of an ion-chip is a boolean value. Therefore, you cannot set 'none' or 'outline' to it as they are strings. Therefore, it would just be enough to check and return output of obs.total > 0 to the outline attribute.

Ref: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/chip